# Why is an infinite set countable if its elements can be enumerated as a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis

I recently read a proof of why $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ is countable.

It simply reads:

> $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ is countable since it may be enumerated in the logical sequence:
>   $$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}...$$
>   where you delete any fraction which has already appeared in another form.

I don't understand why such an enumeration assures that a bijection exists between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$?

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain this.

Jack

Comment: The enumeration *is* the bijection.  From the perspective of $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$ to $\Bbb N$ you have the first element in the sequence maps to $1$.  The second element in the sequence maps to $2$, etc... the $n$'th element in the sequence maps to $n$.  Perhaps it is easier to view the bijection from the other way around from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$.  $1$ maps to the first element in the sequence.  $2$ maps to the second element in the sequence.  $n$ maps to the $n$'th element in the sequence, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you're saying. But without a general rule (which explicitly tells you what $n$ is mapped to), how do you know that the enumeration corresponds to an injective and surjective function?

Comment: It should be clear that there is one and only one $n$'th element in the sequence.  It should also be clear that the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with $1\leq a< b$ occurs at least once since it appeared in the original sequence before it was truncated, and that it cannot occur more than once in the truncated sequence because we said we deleted any fraction from the sequence that occurred after another that it is equal to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map from $\mathbb{N}$ to a set $X$ is a sequence.  In other words, the sequence $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots\}$ can also be thought of as a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ where $f(n)=x_n$.

In the example that you give, the described list is a sequence of fractions in $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$.  Note that, even though you don't have a *formula*, you have a sequence.  In fact, the formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term would be to compute the first $n-1$ terms and figure out the next term.

If you can show that no term repeats in the sequence, then the corresponding map is injective.  If you can show that every fraction appears in the sequence (somewhere), then the corresponding map is surjective.

In the example, the rule for the sequence is $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$, and, if $x_{n-1}=\frac{p}{q}$, then $x_n$ is the next fraction $\frac{r}{q}$ with $q>r>p$ that has not already appeared (therefore the sequence is injective) or $\frac{1}{q+1}$.  The map is surjective because if $\frac{a}{q}$ is written in lowest terms, then it appears when you're considering all fractions with $q$ in the denominator.

You can make the surjectivity more precise: suppose that $x_{n-1}=\frac{p}{q}<\frac{a}{q}<\frac{r}{q}=x_n$.  By the construction rule, $\frac{a}{q}$ would only be skipped if $\frac{a}{q}$ already appears in the sequence, but this can't happen if $\frac{a}{q}$ is in lowest terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it true that, in general, if you can find a logical enumeration of a set, then that implies the set is countable?

Comment: Yes, because an enumeration *is* a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set.

Comment: But will the enumeration always be bijective?

Comment: The third paragraph in the answer describes when the sequence is bijective.  If you mean an enumeration that is a sequence that includes all elements and there are no repeats, then, yes, an enumeration is bijective.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to see that it exists in the following way.  Suppose we first start with the redundant list

$$
\frac12, \frac13, \frac23, \frac14, \frac24, \frac34, \ldots
$$

where we do *not* eliminate duplicate values.  It should be easy to see that the first value has denominator $2$, the next two values have denominator $3$, the next three values have denominator $4$, etc.  This allows us to write down a simple expression for the position index, in the list, of the (unreduced) fraction $\frac{p}{q}$, for $0 < p < q$: If we set

$$
k = \frac{(q-1)(q-2)}{2}+p
$$

then the $k$th value in the list is $\frac{p}{q}$; for instance, for $p = 2, q = 4$, we get $k = 5$.  (Try it!)

Now, suppose that you do as the problem suggests, and eliminate all the duplicate values.  This will make the list one-to-one with its indices.  It will also, unfortunately, change the position index of $\frac{p}{q}$ in a complex way.

However, there's one thing we can be sure of: Because values are only eliminated, and only when they are duplicated, those position indices can only decrease.  It will never be the case that a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ had a finite index before, but now that we've eliminated some values, it somehow no longer has a finite index, or fails to appear anymore.

Hopefully, that will help you see that the list is a bijection in the desired way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that might help you.

1. [Look up a proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20is%20Q%20countable) of the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.
2. [Convince yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=subset+of+countable+is+countable/search?q=subset%20of%20countable%20is%20countable) that if $X$ is countable and $Y\subseteq X$, then $Y$ is countable.

---

EDIT 1: If the above isn't helpful and you want something more explicit. Then label the numbers in your sequence:
$$
x_1 = \frac{1}{2}, x_ 2 = \frac{1}{3}, x_ 3 = \frac{2}{3}, x_ 4 = \frac{1}{4}, x_ 5 = \frac{3}{4}, x_ 6 = \frac{1}{5}, x_ 7 = \frac{2}{5}, x_9 = \frac{3}{5}, x_9 = \frac{4}{5}\dots
$$
Then your bijection $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to (0,\infty)$ is
$$
\phi(m) = x_m.
$$

---

EDIT 2: In all this you have to remember the definition of countable. A set $X$ is countable if there exists surjective function $\phi: \mathbb{N}\to X$. And clearly the above function is surjective. Note that you actually don't need bijectivity. So, by definition, to show that something is countable you just need the function that is surjective. This works because of the definition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I probably should have been clearer in the question. I'm more interested in why this technique of proof works, rather than the result. Why, if you can logically enumerate the elements of a set in a sequence, does that guarantee the set is countable?

Comment: Countable and existence of enumeration are the same thing.

Comment: @Jack: Let me update my answer a bit more.

Comment: I've read your update @Thomas, thanks. You say the function is "clearly surjective". Of course this feels true, but it doesn't seem like a strong mathematical argument?

Comment: @Jack: You were the one who wrote down the sequence that goes through the entire set $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$. It sounds like what you really want to know is how to enumerate the numbers in the set?